# Zenity remote display text issue

Tags: ssh, remote, zenity

When i run command:

```
ssh user@host "zenity --warning --width=500 --no-wrap --text="Your $VPN is not connected. Please connect it or inform to engineer" --display=:0"
```

If I use single quote then it works fine but there is a variable so I had to use double quote and It display like:

[image]

Comment: Check your first double quote `"` to a single quote `'` to match your ending which should be single quote only.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've modified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use single quotes for the message like this:

```
ssh user@host "zenity --warning --width=500 --no-wrap --text='Your $VPN is not connected. Please connect it or inform to engineer' --display=:0"
```

Or escape the double quotes for the message like this:

```
ssh user@host "zenity --warning --width=500 --no-wrap --text=\"Your $VPN is not connected. Please connect it or inform to engineer\" --display=:0"
```